# Wordpress $wpdb - Safest way to Query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, pdo

So as many already know the $wpdb class in Wordpress can't deal with inserts and updates involving NULL values.  This is a major headache, and there doesn't seem to be a good way around it.

So I'm wondering what the next best way is to insert/update tables in Wordpress?  I liked WPDB cause of the prepared statements, so I was hoping to have something where I could continue with that.  Unfortunately, no PDO support?

Any suggestions?

Comment: If PDO is not supported, why tag your question PDO?

Comment: because if theres another prepared statement option (such as Wordpress's built in WPDB) i would love to hear it, because PDO functionality is really what I'm interested in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Here**](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/bug-fix-wpdb-insert-amp-update-with-null-values) is a solution for `Null` values, just create a new `class` by extending the `wpdb` class and use two new `insert` and `update` functions and to do this you can create a `db.php` file in your `wp-content` directory and drop [**this**](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4012111/db.php) content in the file.

Not tested but you may give it a try.

Comment: I did see this solution, but for whatever reason it didn't work for me initially.  But I'll play around with it.  thanks!